# Custom alert rule for PODS and Clusters

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to set up some alerts in Prometheus. I am able to create the alerts for nodes for the following category (network utilization, CPU usage, memory usage). I am stuck with the pods.

Which metrics should I use for PODs/Containers/clusters alert rule?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus kubernetes metrics all begins with kube_[SOMETHING], if you have datas exported to prometheus connect go to the prometheus interface and try typing kube in it, it will propose you autocmopletion with available metrics.